# how to make legend bar to thinner

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have data like this

```
Year,stations,Views
2015,1,100
2015,2,85
2015,3,75
2015,4,25
2015,5,10
2015,6,100
.........
2022,12,100
```

and i plotted the bar graph using this code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator, ScalarFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 0.8 #set the value globally

plt.rcParams['xtick.major.pad']='1' #control gap betwn axis and its nos
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.pad']='1'
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman'] + plt.rcParams['font.serif']
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 3
plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.size'] = 1.6
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 0.9
plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.width'] = 0.9
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.size'] = 3
plt.rcParams['ytick.minor.size'] = 1.6
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.width'] = 0.9
plt.rcParams['ytick.minor.width'] = 0.9
plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = True

df=pd.read_csv("input.csv")
print(df)


month_dict = {1 : "BiD", 2 : "BCD", 3 : "BTY", 4 : "HJY", 
              5 : "GGH" , 6 : "GHY", 7 : "JHT", 8 : "JRT", 
              9 : "KTY", 10 : "MNY" ,11 : "NTY",12 : "NRT", 
              13 : "PGH", 14 : "RTY" ,15 : "RER",16 : "RAS",
              17 : "STT", 18 : "TYU" ,19 : "UIU",20 : "UTY",
              21 : "UII", 22 : "UII" ,23 : "UII",24 : "UII",
              25 : "UII", 26 : "UII" ,27 : "UII",28 : "UII",
              29 : "UII", 30 : "UII"}

df.pivot('Year','stations','Views').rename(columns=month_dict).plot.bar(figsize = (10.5,5.8),width=0.7)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0), prop={'size': 7.2},frameon=False)
```

and this code generates the plot as [image: plot]

I want to make the legend symbol bar to be thinner,however it is not currently possible using `plt.legend` command while using df.pivot, I hope experts may help me solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some parameters:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator, ScalarFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 0.8 #set the value globally

plt.rcParams['xtick.major.pad']='1' #control gap betwn axis and its nos
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.pad']='1'
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman'] + plt.rcParams['font.serif']
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 3
plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.size'] = 1.6
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 0.9
plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.width'] = 0.9
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.size'] = 3
plt.rcParams['ytick.minor.size'] = 1.6
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.width'] = 0.9
plt.rcParams['ytick.minor.width'] = 0.9
plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = True
plt.rcParams['legend.handlelength']=0.2
df=pd.read_csv("thinner.csv")
print(df)


month_dict = {1 : "BiD", 2 : "BCD", 3 : "BTY", 4 : "HJY", 
              5 : "GGH" , 6 : "GHY", 7 : "JHT", 8 : "JRT", 
              9 : "KTY", 10 : "MNY" ,11 : "NTY",12 : "NRT", 
              13 : "PGH", 14 : "RTY" ,15 : "RER",16 : "RAS",
              17 : "STT", 18 : "TYU" ,19 : "UIU",20 : "UTY",
              21 : "UII", 22 : "UII" ,23 : "UII",24 : "UII",
              25 : "UII", 26 : "UII" ,27 : "UII",28 : "UII",
              29 : "UII", 30 : "UII"}

df.pivot('Year','stations','Views').rename(columns=month_dict).plot.bar(figsize = (10.5,5.8),width=0.7)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0), prop={'size': 7.2},frameon=False)
```

so, I added:

```
plt.rcParams['legend.handlelength']=0.2
```

if you want to mak it thinner add:

```
plt.rcParams['legend.handleheight']=0.05 #or whatever height you want
```

For other parameters of legend:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

[image]

Comment: no symbol height is not changing only width, what to do inorder to change the legend symbol height of the symbol,

Comment: Are you looking to change the font width?

Comment: legend symbol i need to make thinner it looks thick like a box

Comment: legend symbols presenting in different color boxes i need to make thin

Comment: legend symbol  = The color boxes?

Comment: yes u r right @Serge, but the text written near legend symbol should be unchanged

Comment: Try with ```plt.rcParams['legend.handlelength']=0.2```.  I chose 0.4 in my answer, but you want it even smaller.

Comment: actually i want to make it little lengthy but height should be reduced or if u r using the  plt.rcParams['legend.handlelength']=0.2 its length become small but height is more

Comment: can u solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74803810/plotting-the-data-availability-using-the-data-set?noredirect=1#comment132020154_74803810

Comment: Actually trying to. If this is the answer you were looking for, don't forget to check it as accepted.